# Static variable accessing php 5.2 and greater

Tags: php

Will the following code work on php 5.2+? I am creating a static variable that instances will need to access, but I am not sure if all the code I am writing is valid in php 5.2 (I am running php 5.4).

Also is this the proper way to set static variables?

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    static $report_db;

    public function get_report_db()
    {
        return self::$report_db;
    }
}

$CI =& get_instance();
include APPPATH.'config/database.php';

//If we have a reporting database load it and use it for all reporting functions
if (isset($db['report']))
{
    MY_Model::$report_db = $CI->load->database('report', TRUE); 
}
else
{
    MY_Model::$report_db = $CI->load->database('default', TRUE);    
}
?>
```

Comment: It will work, but maybe not as you expected. Changes made between instances may not be 'saved'

Comment: I don't want to save report_db for each instance, I just want to have a variable that is the same for all instances.

Comment: Not possible. Use database instead

Comment: It seems that it is working great. As I understand a static variable is NOT tied to an instance. It is a variable that only has one copy per class therefore there is just one copy. It seems to be doing what I need.

Comment: Well, maybe I did not understand you correctly :) If it fits your needs, then great :-)